# How to initialize array of objects with a specific generic type?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, initialization

I have tried the following methods:

```java
Optional[] arr1 = new Optional[0]; // Warning: Raw use of parameterized class 'Optional'

Optional<Integer>[] arr2 = new Optional[0]; // Warning: Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.Optional[]' to 'java.util.Optional<java.lang.Integer>[]'

Optional<Integer>[] arr3 = new Optional<Integer>[0]; // Error: Generic array creation
```

What is the problem with each different initialization above?

What would be the correct initialization method, enabling type resolution and safety in future access to the array?

*Java 8*

Comment: You can't create an array of a generic type because of [how generics work](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Comment: I think you'll appreciate: [*Optional - The Mother of all Bikesheds*](https://inside.java/2017/04/11/optional/).

Comment: Whoever closed this question, should take another look. I am not creating an "array of generic type" like `T[]`. I am creating an array of a certain *known* type, which has a generic parameter.